# Detect HTML5 in c#

Tags: c#, html, file-io

I'm trying to make an uploadpage which would make it possible to either add multiple elements with HTML5:

```
<input id="bleh" name="bleh" type="file" multiple="multiple" runat="server" size="20" />
```

and if it's not supported I'd give them an uploadfield that can be multiplied with javascript, it's all written down but a lot to copypaste so not really worth getting that up.

What I'm trying to achieve now, is to detect if the client has html5 to support the multiple-file upload, is this even possible?

What I'd like to get as a result is

```
if(//checkhtml5)
    //activate the part with the multiple input field
else
    //activate the part with the single field that can get duplicated
```

so the question is: how could I do the html5 check? Is it even possible? Is there another way around?

Comment: This question doesn't make sense since HTML5 is a client side language and checking for HTML5 capabilities must be done on the client side. C# is a server side language and cannot run on the client. The HTML5 capabilities should be checked with javascript and not C#.

Comment: wow. Html5 is client side language, and C# is server side language, I don't think there is any way you can detect it through c#, however, you can detect it at client side itself and then send a request to server for appropriate action

Comment: The browsers send an `UserAgent` attribute in its requests. Use it to identify the browser and from it learn if such version supports HTML5

Comment: Well it makes sense because I don't know if there is a way or not, that's why I'm asking ^^ And I did some research for the client-side searching for exemple: http://diveintohtml5.info/detect.html but that won't work out because I'm working with a specific input-type and that isn't supported in Modernizr etc. So that's why I'm asking here, what I should do. Client or Server-side, as long as I can use both uploadways dynamicly changing either the client has html5 or not.

Comment: @SJuan76 So you suggest I should get the browser out of it, and make a checklist if they either support html5 or not myself? That would indeed be a possibility thanks

Comment: The `UserAgent` can be spoofed and hence is not a very reliable way of identifying HTML5 capabilities.

Comment: Doing feature detection by interpreting user agent is probably the worst way of doing it. Aside from user agent spoofing, the list is never going to cover all possibilities so you're bound to disqualify browsers that would have the feature. And would you update the list every time a new browser version comes out (which is to say, very often)?

Comment: That's indeed why I didn't opt for that choice right away but if it's the only way, I don't really see how I could do it the other way except for the answer below

Comment: What's wrong with the answer below?

Comment: Well, even without html5 he'll add the multiple attribute and will check it as true even if it doesn't executes it on the page it is "physicly" present in the code. So his check would be good if the program ignored the "setAttribute" but it doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I'd do is something like this on the client side:

```
var elem = document.createElement("input");
elem.setAttribute("multiple", "true");
var isMultipleSupported = elem.multiple === true;

if (isMultipleSupported)
  ...
else
  ...
```

Comment: Looks like what I'd need indeed, but I'm not really good at html/js could you tell me what just happens at: var isMultipleSupported = elem.multiple === true; ? I never saw triple "=" before and how I interpret this is that you firstly add the multiple possibility to the inputfield and after that you check if it's there. So I guess that if the html wouldn't support multiple he'd ignore the "setattribute" is that it?

Comment: `===` not only compares the value but also the type. So the type has to be boolean and the value has to be true. Only then will the equality be true. If the browser doesn't support `multiple` then the attribute would not be set as a boolean (it would still be there but as a string) and the comparison would be false.

Comment: Note that you do not need to append `elem` to the DOM. The `createElement` is only for checking if `multiple` is supported. If `multiple` is supported then add the correct `input` in the `true` case in the if-statement and vice versa in the `false` case.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation ! Happy new year btw

Answer (score 1):

Check out Modernizr for detecting browser capabilties. Its a well supported JavaScript library...

You should not check for a specific browser/browserversion as they change faster than you be able to keep up.

Checking for features/capabilities is much saver.

But: nothing here is C#. You could check only IN the browser for the capabilities vie JS.
Put your razor stuff (I guess you user MVC for generating the page) accordingly. Enable parts of your page handling the uploading via JS.

Comment: Checked out Modernizr but it can't be applied for what I try to do sadly. unless I get it totally wrong, but the checks they make aren't on that one special attribute.

Comment: I think it can detect it. At least in the input.js capability checkup it is mentioned. Have not tried it though.
https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/06d79fb179e95f35d509afbe7e209403e3791be9/feature-detects/input.js

Comment: Sweet it's in it, must have missed it, thanks!